# R, incident matrix, remove named columns based on their column sums

Tags: r, matrix

In an incident matrix with named columns, I want to remove columns with only ones in them.

For instance in

```
        a    b    c
1       0    1    1
1       1    0    1
```

column c should be removed. I think about somethink like this:

```
colnames(featureMatrix)[]

# get column names of 1-cols
useless <- colnames(matrix)[?]

# remove columns
matrix <- matrix[,!colnames(matrix) %in% useless ]
```

What is missing is the condition based on the column sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0,1,1),2)
rownames(m) <- c(1,1)
colnames(m) <- c("a","b","c")

m[,colMeans(m)!=1]
#   a b
# 1 0 1
# 1 1 0
```